# VLCKit (iOS) mediaPlayer suddenly stops playing

Tags: swift, vlckit

I'm first-time user of MobileVLCKit-iOS (3.3.15) and have added VLCMediaPlayer() in a swift app to play audio urls. Randomly the mediaplayer receives a mediaPlayerStateChanged(.stopped) event, after buffering or immediately when executing play(). In other cases this audio url plays just fine.
What could be the reason for suddenly stopping? What can I do to solve this ? Unfortunately I receive no (error)info from the player...
Thanks for any advice
Frank

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be no issue, probably has to do with the audio urls.